# mysql single table SELECT query ORDER BY causes FILESORT

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by, filesort

I looked through multiple similar posts trying to get input on how to redefine my index but can't figure this out. Every time i include the ORDER BY statement, it uses filesort to return the resultset.

Here's the table definition and query:

```
SELECT
    `s`.`title`,
    `s`.`price`,
    `s`.`price_sale`
  FROM `style` `s`
 WHERE `s`.`isactive`=1 AND `s`.`department`='women' 
  ORDER
     BY `s`.`ctime` DESC



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `style` (
    `id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `ctime` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `department` char(5)  NOT NULL,
    `isactive` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `price` float(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `price_sale` float(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    KEY `idx_grid_default` (`isactive`,`department`,`ctime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;
```

Also, here's the explain result set I get:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref  | idx_grid      | idx_grid | 6       | const,const |    3 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: I tested your setup and the index seems to be used just fine, why do you think a filesort is being used?
   EXPLAIN SELECT   `s`.`title`,...
[...]
possible_keys: idx_grid_default
key: idx_grid_default
Extra: Using where

Comment: that's weird - I get a "Using where; Using filesort" - see my explain above

Comment: Erm, so what if you get `using filesort`? What's exactly troubling you with that? Do you consider that to be wrong or? Do you know what it means?

Comment: if it's using filesort to return the result set it's not entirely relying on the index to do the job - which adds extra waiting time for the query to execute. Performance is the goal here.

Answer (score 3):

**Why does `s.isactive` not get used as an index?**

MySQL (or any SQL for that matter) will not use a key if it has low cardinality.
In plain English, if many rows share the same value for a key, (My)SQL will not use the index, but just real the table instead.

A boolean field almost never gets picked as an index because of this; too many rows share the same value.

**Why does MySQL not use the index on ctime?**

`ctime` is included in a multi-field or `composite` index. MySQL will only use a composite index **if** you use all of it or a left-most part of it <sup>*)</sup>
If you sort on the middle or rightmost field(s) of a composite index, MySQL cannot use the index and will have to resort to filesort.
So a `order by isactive , department` will use an index;
`order by department` will not.
`order by isactive` will **also not** use an index, but that's because the cardinality of the boolean field `isactive` is too low.

*) there are some exceptions, but this covers 97% of cases.

**Links:**
Cardinality wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

[What does Using filesort mean in MySQL?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/)

It does not mean you have a temporary file, it just mean a sort is done (bad name, ignore the 4 first letters).

from **Baron Schwartz**:

> The truth is, filesort is badly named. Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. It has nothing to do with files. Filesort should be called “sort.” It is quicksort at heart.